# Terminal Server Excel export

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I have an application I have exported as a RemoteApp via a 2008 R2 (recently upgraded from 2008) terminal server.

Ever since the upgrade the excel export function of this app (which actually opens a copy of Excel) has been running *much* more slowly than would be expected than previously. 
My best estimate is at least a magnitude of order (possibly two) slower.

When I log in with a standard desktop session to this system (even using the TS gateway settings defined for the RemoteApp) things function normally.

Where should I look to debug this issue? There isn't anything unusual going on in the event logs.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you "export to excel" in IE, doesn't it use the clipboard in some fashion?  I would assume Excel would work in a similiar fashion.  Maybe as a data handler or something?  The reason I mention this is that its possible that the clipboard contents are being copied to the local machine over RDP in which case your lag might be related to the data being copied.  I am unfamiliar with RemoteApp, so I can't really comment.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with 32/64 bit print conversion, specifically a problem with how the Remote Desktop / Terminal Server easy print functions work.

I asked another question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/394582/splwow64-with-ts-easy-print) about the specifics of this problem now that I've tracked it down.